# как узнать сколько ресурсов потребляет мое node.js приложение

Tags: node.js, сервер, производительность, тестирование

Всем привет. Я делаю сервер на ноде, я уже практически сделал всю основную работу и теперь задумался о размещении его как бы в продакшене. Но пока только задумался.

У меня есть слабенький сервер на котором я всё тестирую и показываю другим людям. Сейчас я даже написал приложение, которое как бы имитирует действия пользователей. Я сделал много подключений, обвалил свой сервер и всё отлично. Но я, например, не знаю что на моём сервере было узким местом когда он упал.

У меня в голове это выглядит как-то так: есть показатель оперативной памяти, ресурсов процессора и, наверно, сети (загруженность канала или что-то такое). Измерив эти показатели под нагрузкой я мог бы понять чего моему приложению хватает с запасом, а чего - нет. Тогда я мог бы прикинуть сколько пользователей я ожидаю видеть на своём сайте и, соответственно, насколько сильный сервер мне нужен.

Я себе это как-то так представляю, но, возможно, это наивно. И я даже не могу сформулировать вопрос для гугла. Наверняка у программистов есть какой-то англоязычный термин для обозначения этих дел, но я его не знаю.

Короче вопрос такой: есть ли инструменты с помощью которых можно посчитать сколько использовано оперативки, процессора и сети в тот момент когда я нагружаю свой сервер. Ну и какие-то более общие советы/информация по этой теме мне бы не помешали.

Comment: Что касается терминов, по котрым надо гуглить, то для Windows - "performance counters". Довольно мощная штука, котрая позволяет померить много всего и увидеть измеренное на графиках, можно начать отсюда: https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/optimization/level1/1_2.php

Comment: а есть что-то для линукса?)